# Анонимные функции в JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, отладка

Есть страница, в ней только одна JS-вставка:

```
<script>
<!--
 var timevalue= 230 * 1000; function az(t) {
    return ((t*1<10)?'0':'')+t;
}

function BeginCount(timeval) {
    timeval-=1000;&page=test&action=end_test&timer=1";
    var d=new Date;
    d.setTime(timeval);
    var h="", m="", s="";
    m=d.getMinutes();
    s=d.getSeconds();
    h=((timeval/1000)-m*60-s)
    h=az(h);
    m=az(m);
    s=az(s);
    document.forms['form1'].elements['edit1'].value=h + ":" + m + " " + s;
    window.setTimeout('BeginCount(' + timeval + ')', 1000);
}

BeginCount(timevalue);
//-->
</script>
```

Таймер идёт начиная с 10 минут, и этот код обновляет таймер.
Только вот даже если стереть/изменить этот код ничего не будет, таймер как шёл  так и идёт, не изменяя своего времени.

Пробовал в консоли вызвать

> BeginCount(9999999);

таймер меняется от 999999 секунд, потом снова становится стандартное значение(минус то время что прошло) и дальше спокойно ведет отсчет.

В консоли Google chrome я понял, что каждую секунду вызывается анонимный скрипт.
Я использовал шаги и понял, что каждую секунду вызывается анонимный скрипт

> VM[****].js

в котором устанавливается таймер

> BeginCount(40380)

То есть где-то есть функция которая вызывает этот таймер, её можно как-то отыскать?

P.S Даже когда я в консоли делаю приостановку выполнения скриптов, а потом перезагружаю страницу, отсчет всё равно с того времени как и обычно, ничего не меняя стартовое минус прошедшее....

Comment: Ну, VM[****].js - это работа виртуальной машины.

А функция, которая вызывается каждую секунду осуществляется через setTimeout внутри самой BeginCount, вот здесь: `window.setTimeout( 'BeginCount(' + timeval + ')' , 1000);`

Comment: А причём тут "анонимные функции в js"?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Устанавливается глобальная переменная, содержащая значения счетчика обратного отсчета
var timevalue = 230 * 1000;

// дополнение значения нулями
function az(t) {
    return ((t * 1 < 10) ? '0' : '') + t;
}

function BeginCount(timeval) {
    // С каждым вызовом BeginCount
    // значение счетчика уменьшается на 1 секунду
    timeval -= 1000;
    // создается объект даты
    var d = new Date;
    // ему устанавливается время таймера
    d.setTime(timeval);
    var h = "", m = "", s = "";
    // из объекта извлекаются минуты
    m = d.getMinutes();
    // секунды
    s = d.getSeconds();
    // Считается количество часов
    h = ((timeval / 1000) - m * 60 - s)
    // эти значения преобразуются в строку дополнением нулями если необходимо
    h = az(h);
    m = az(m);
    s = az(s);

    // в элемент формы проставляется значения таймера
    document.forms['form1'].elements['edit1'].value = h + ":" + m + " " + s;
    // устанавливается повторный вызов таймера, через секунду
    window.setTimeout('BeginCount(' + timeval + ')', 1000);
}

// вызывается фунцция обновляющая значения счетчика
BeginCount(timevalue);
```

Соответственно, можно изменить значение счетчика только в рантайме изменив значение глобальной переменной **timevalue**, например через консоль.Если есть доступ к исходному коду странички, то можно просто поправить значение

Comment: Значения изменял - никакого эффекта.